# Python Pandas Warning Message

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing an assignment in Jupyter Notebook using Python/Pandas

I have to do this: If a game is selected from the dataset at random, determine the probability that: It's 'Amazing' given that it was released before 2000.

I wrote this bit of code which seems to work:

```
amazingPhraseCount = data[data["score_phrase"] == "Amazing"][data["release_year"] < 2000]["score_phrase"].count()
pAmazingLess2000 = amazingPhraseCount/platformCount
print("Probability it's amazing given it was released before 2000: " + str(Round(pAmazingLess2000, 4)))
```

But I get this warning:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:26: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

So I'm worried the value I got from the code I wrote might be incorrect. I just don't understand the warning.

**Note: platformCount was defined in previous code. data is a variable dataframe that reads from a csv file using csv_read**

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting chained indexing ... twice. The docs [explicitly discourage](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) chained indexing *at all*. Indeed, I do not believe it is *ever* appropriate. At best, it's ambiguous but works; more likely it will introduce errors.

In fact, you don't need to filter your dataframe at all. Your calculations are possible with Boolean series:

```
# calculate total number pre-2000
year_mask = data['release_year'] < 2000
amazing_mask = data['score_phrase'] == 'Amazing'

# calculate probability amazing given pre-2000
res = (year_mask & amazing_mask).sum() / year_mask.sum()
```

The above calculations are natural with Python / Pandas since `True` / `False` values are considered equivalent to `1` / `0` respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much but shouldn't you do year_mask.count() in the denominator of the probability ratio? Because you're counting all the occurrences of that item.

Comment: @Katie2423, No, you want sum all the `True` values in a Boolean series.